# Upgrade error: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on entity type node

Tags: 8, upgrading

I am struggling with Drupal 8 upgrade for a months now. The Travis CI build is always failed with below errors.

I'm upgrading from Drupal 8.3.7 to 8.4.8 with Lightning (2.2.9), BLT 8.9.7, Drush version 8.2.3

```
Synchronized configuration: update views.view.frontpage.             [ok]
Synchronized configuration: update dropzonejs.settings.              [ok]
Synchronized configuration: update lightning_roles.settings.         [ok]
Finalizing configuration synchronization.                            [ok]
The import failed due for the following reasons:                     [error]
Unexpected error during import with operation delete for
node.type.page: Attempt to create a field body that does not exist on
entity type node.
Unexpected error during import with operation delete for
node.type.landing_page: Attempt to create a field body that does not
exist on entity type node.
```

I've successfully upgraded on localhost and exported the config file using `"drush [mywebsite] cex sync"` command. However, when I push to Github the Travis CI build failed with the errors above.

I've done the "`drush [mysite] updb`" command and it went without any errors.  I also ran the command "`drush [mysite] entity-updates -y`"

Googling the errors without any luck, so I thought to post it here.  Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the config for field.storage.node.body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to manually create a "body" field in my landing_page content type.  Once I created the body field, the error no longer show up.

This can be apply to any other fields is show up in the error.

Comment: +1 agree. I've create some instructions for a technique to create the body field, here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/294133/1082